# Using a JSON return in ngrepeat

Tags: json, angularjs

I am getting a json return but for some reason I am not able to use it in my ng repeat, I can return the object raw and display it , just not sure how to set it to parse properly

here is the json I am getting

```
{"COLUMNS":["SUCCESS","RETMESSAGE","EVENTID","EVENTTYPEID","EVENTNAME","EVENTDESC","STARTDATE","ENDDATE","CITY","STATE","COUNTRY","VENUE","EVENTWEBSITE","HOTELWEBSITE","CREATEDDATE","UPDATEDDATE","ISDELETED","DELETEDDATE","FEATURED","TYPENAME","EVENTIMAGEID","LOGOFILETYPE","IMAGECOUNT"],"DATA":[[true,"All Events Found!",7,5,"Europa Test Games 2015","","July, 17 2015 00:00:00","July, 19 2015 00:00:00","","0","USA","","","","July, 15 2015 09:50:12","July, 24 2015 11:05:48",false,null,false,"Testing Event Type",19,"jpg",10],[true,"All Events Found!",8,6,"Test1","","January, 01 1900 00:00:00","January, 01 1900 00:00:00","","0","USA","","","","July, 15 2015 10:31:16","July, 15 2015 10:31:16",false,null,false,"Event 2",null,null,3],[true,"All Events Found!",10,9,"Test3","","January, 01 1900 00:00:00","January, 01 1900 00:00:00","","0","USA","","","","July, 15 2015 10:33:42","July, 15 2015 10:33:42",false,null,false,"New Type ",null,null,1],[true,"All Events Found!",11,7,"Test4","","January, 01 1900 00:00:00","January, 01 1900 00:00:00","","0","USA","","","","July, 15 2015 10:34:55","July, 15 2015 10:34:55",false,null,false,"Event one",null,null,0],[true,"All Events Found!",13,8,"Test6","","January, 01 1900 00:00:00","January, 01 1900 00:00:00","","0","USA","","","","July, 15 2015 10:36:59","July, 15 2015 10:36:59",false,null,false,"Test",21,"png",0],[true,"All Events Found!",14,8,"Tulip Event","","July, 31 2015 00:00:00","August, 01 2015 00:00:00","","0","USA","","","","July, 15 2015 10:44:04","July, 15 2015 10:44:04",false,null,false,"Test",25,"jpg",0],[true,"All Events Found!",16,7,"Google Chrome","This is a test in Google Chrome ","July, 15 2015 00:00:00","August, 01 2015 00:00:00","Here","WA","USA","My Place","","","July, 15 2015 11:06:52","July, 15 2015 11:06:52",false,null,false,"Event one",27,"jpg",0],[true,"All Events Found!",17,7,"Add an Image","Add an Image Test ","January, 01 1900 00:00:00","January, 01 1900 00:00:00","","CA","USA","","","","July, 15 2015 11:08:45","July, 15 2015 11:08:45",false,null,false,"Event one",28,"png",2],[true,"All Events Found!",18,1,"Missing Data Test","This is a test for missing data after an add. Added new comment for update purposes","January, 01 1900 00:00:00","January, 01 1900 00:00:00","Area","ID","USA","My Place","esc.dev.europa-sports.net","esc.dev.europa-sports.net","July, 15 2015 11:24:11","August, 06 2015 11:49:32",false,null,true,"Top Industry Events",75,"tmp",0],[true,"All Events Found!",19,5,"event namer","tester","January, 01 1900 00:00:00","January, 01 1900 00:00:00","city","NE","USA","venue","","","July, 15 2015 11:46:17","July, 15 2015 11:46:43",false,null,false,"Testing Event Type",32,"jpg",0],[true,"All Events Found!",21,6,"Name Change","e","May, 01 2015 00:00:00","June, 01 2015 00:00:00","e","WA","USA","e","","","July, 15 2015 12:46:29","July, 15 2015 13:56:05",false,null,false,"Event 2",37,"jpg",1],[true,"All Events Found!",22,5,"IE TEST","IE TEST ADD COMMENT","January, 01 2015 00:00:00","January, 06 2015 00:00:00","NOT HERE","NE","USA","ANYWHERE","MYSPACE.COM","","July, 15 2015 13:44:44","July, 15 2015 13:48:27",false,null,false,"Testing Event Type",39,"jpg",1],[true,"All Events Found!",24,6,"event me now! ","BOOM! ","December, 03 2015 00:00:00","December, 05 2015 00:00:00","Your town","AK","USA","My house","not here","","July, 16 2015 08:33:27","July, 16 2015 08:33:27",false,null,false,"Event 2",null,null,0],[true,"All Events Found!",25,5,"event me now!!","BAM! ","December, 03 2015 00:00:00","December, 05 2015 00:00:00","Your town","AZ","USA","My Place","","","July, 16 2015 08:35:08","July, 16 2015 08:35:08",false,null,false,"Testing Event Type",null,null,0],[true,"All Events Found!",26,5,"KJLFDSJKLFDKJL","BAM","December, 03 2015 00:00:00","December, 05 2015 00:00:00","Your town","AL","USA","My House","","","July, 16 2015 08:35:52","July, 16 2015 08:35:52",false,null,false,"Testing Event Type",null,null,0],[true,"All Events Found!",27,6,"FDSJKLSDFSFDJKL","BAM","December, 03 2015 00:00:00","December, 05 2015 00:00:00","Your town","AZ","USA","My Place","","","July, 16 2015 08:38:35","July, 16 2015 08:38:35",false,null,false,"Event 2",null,null,0],[true,"All Events Found!",29,6,"cvxbvcbvcbcv","dfvdfvdf","December, 03 2015 00:00:00","December, 05 2015 00:00:00","My town","AZ","USA","My Place","","","July, 16 2015 09:19:38","July, 16 2015 09:22:13",false,null,false,"Event 2",44,"jpg",0],[true,"All Events Found!",30,14,"fvsbzdfb sdf","","December, 13 2015 00:00:00","December, 15 2015 00:00:00","","0","USA","","","","July, 16 2015 09:23:03","July, 16 2015 09:23:03",false,null,false,"CREATE EVENT TYPE",45,"jpg",0],[true,"All Events Found!",31,5,"EVENT NAMEY","BAM","December, 03 2015 00:00:00","December, 05 2015 00:00:00","Your town","AZ","USA","My Place","HERE","","July, 16 2015 10:00:58","July, 16 2015 10:01:51",false,null,false,"Testing Event Type",46,"jpg",2],[true,"All Events Found!",32,6,"event me now!!!!","HTR","December, 03 2015 00:00:00","December, 05 2015 00:00:00","Your town","AZ","USA","My Place","","","July, 16 2015 10:06:49","July, 16 2015 10:19:51",false,null,false,"Event 2",49,"jpg",1],[true,"All Events Found!",33,1,"This is a test event","","October, 01 2015 00:00:00","October, 03 2015 00:00:00","","0","USA","","","","July, 23 2015 15:13:00","July, 24 2015 11:23:10",false,null,true,"Top Industry Events",52,"png",1],[true,"All Events Found!",34,6,"RYAN","RYAN RETEST ON DEV","December, 05 2016 00:00:00","December, 06 2016 00:00:00","YES","AK","USA","YES","","","July, 24 2015 11:21:55","July, 24 2015 11:22:50",false,null,true,"Event 2",54,"jpg",0],[true,"All Events Found!",35,6,"JKLDFSJKLFSD","FKLGFKJGFKJ","September, 25 2017 00:00:00","September, 30 2017 00:00:00","KJFDJK","AZ","USA","JKSDFJK","","","July, 24 2015 11:23:52","July, 24 2015 11:23:52",false,null,true,"Event 2",55,"jpg",0],[true,"All Events Found!",41,1,"Chris' Big Test Event",null,"August, 05 2015 00:00:00","August, 05 2015 00:00:00",null,null,"USA",null,null,null,"August, 05 2015 14:14:58","August, 05 2015 15:13:24",false,null,false,"Top Industry Events",null,null,0],[true,"All Events Found!",42,1,"Missing Data Test 123","This is a test for missing data after an add. Added new comment for update purposes","January, 01 1900 00:00:00","January, 01 1900 00:00:00","Area","ID","USA","My Place","esc.dev.europa-sports.net","esc.dev.europa-sports.net","August, 05 2015 17:41:42","August, 05 2015 17:41:42",false,null,false,"Top Industry Events",null,null,0],[true,"All Events Found!",43,1,"Missing Data Test 1234","This is a test for missing data after an add. Added new comment for update purposes","January, 01 1900 00:00:00","January, 01 1900 00:00:00","Area","ID","USA","My Place","esc.dev.europa-sports.net","esc.dev.europa-sports.net","August, 05 2015 18:06:49","August, 05 2015 18:06:49",false,null,false,"Top Industry Events",null,null,0],[true,"All Events Found!",44,1,"Missing Data Test 1235","This is a test for missing data after an add. Added new comment for update purposes","January, 01 1900 00:00:00","January, 01 1900 00:00:00","Area","ID","USA","My Place","esc.dev.europa-sports.net","esc.dev.europa-sports.net","August, 05 2015 18:07:44","August, 05 2015 18:07:44",false,null,false,"Top Industry Events",null,null,0],[true,"All Events Found!",45,1,"Missing Data Test 12355","This is a test for missing data after an add. Added new comment for update purposes","January, 01 1900 00:00:00","January, 01 1900 00:00:00","Area","ID","USA","My Place","esc.dev.europa-sports.net","esc.dev.europa-sports.net","August, 05 2015 18:08:41","August, 05 2015 18:08:41",false,null,false,"Top Industry Events",null,null,0]]}
```

And here is my code

//The Factory

```
'use strict';


angular.module('myApp.module.Events.eventsMain.Factory', [])// jshint ignore:line

.factory('EventFactory',// jshint ignore:line
    ['$rootScope','$http',
    function ($rootScope,$http) {
        var service = {};
            $rootScope.serviceMessage = 'This is the about page message from the controller';

            service.listEvents = function (callbackFunc) {

               $http({
                        method: 'GET',
                        url: '/mercury/events/listall.json'
                     }).success(function(data){
                        // With the data succesfully returned, call our callback
                        callbackFunc(data);
                    }).error(function(){
                        alert("error");
                    });
            };


         return service;
    }]);
```

//Controller

```
'use strict';


angular.module('myApp.module.Events.eventsMain.Controller', ['ngRoute','myApp.module.Events.eventsMain.Factory'])// jshint ignore:line


.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.when('/events-main', {
            controller: 'EventController',
            templateUrl: 'com/modules/Events/events-main/views/events-main.html',
            hideMenus: true,
            protectedArea: true,
            title: 'Events Main',
            menuGroup: 'Events',
            description: 'This is the Description of the Events page',
            keywords: 'Events, Events Page',
            breadcrumbList: [{view: '/',title:'Home'},{view: '/events-main', title: 'Events Main'}]
      });
    }])


.controller('EventController',// jshint ignore:line
    ['$scope', 'EventFactory',
    function ($scope, EventFactory) {
        //List of functions that Event uses 

        //This function returns the data from the events service and assigns them to an eventList
        //This variable is what is used for the pagination
        EventFactory.listEvents(function(dataResponse) {
            $scope.dataList = dataResponse;
        });

        //This is the general service message to demo setting a variable and displaying it on the page 
        $scope.message = 'This is the Events page message from the controller';
        //This resets the currentPage on pagination on the events page so every time you go to it , it will reset it to the first page
        $scope.curPage = 0;
        //This sets the number of items that are shown on the page for pagination
        $scope.pageSize = 8;        
    }]);
```

it will return it and dump it on the page if I do {{ dataList}} but I can't seem to use it for my pagination or my ngRepeat, do I need to serialize it at all ? or am I missing something

Here is the ngrepeat

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-6" data-ng-repeat="data in dataList | filter: searchEventText | orderBy: filterEventText | pagination: curPage * pageSize | limitTo: pageSize">
            <div class="thumbnail"><img src="{{ data.pic }}" alt="{{ data.eventname }}" class="img-responsive">
            <div class="caption">
                <h4>{{ data.eventname }}</h4>
                <h5>{{ data.startdate }}</h5>
                <h6>{{ data.eventdesc }}</h6>
                <p><a href="/event-details" class="btn btn-primary" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></span> Details </a>
                </p>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--Row-->
</div><!--Container-->
```

Comment: Show us your `ng-repeat="..."`.

Comment: Let me guess - you have a structure of table in COLUMNS, data in DATA, and you want to display it together? Show us your `ng-repeat`, and we will say, what you did wrong. But if I understand you correctly, than you have a lot of work before you.

Comment: Added the NgRepeat, yeah the columns and data is correct, I was wondering if there was a global parser to turn it into a proper object

Answer (score 0):

The issue was displaying the information accessing it in the function needed to be changed into this

```
EventFactory.listEvents(function(dataResponse) {
            $scope.dataList = dataResponse.data;
        });
```

and showing it was the fun part, since there wasn't access to the columns within the object you had to access them as an array similar to this

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-6" data-ng-repeat="data in dataList | filter: searchEventText | orderBy: filterEventText | pagination: curPage * pageSize | limitTo: pageSize">
            <div class="thumbnail"><img src="{{ data[3] }}" alt="{{ data.eventname }}" class="img-responsive">
            <div class="caption">
                <h4>{{ data[0] }}</h4>
                <h5>{{ data[1] }}</h5>
                <h6>{{ data[2] }}</h6>
                <p><a href="/event-details" class="btn btn-primary" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></span> Details </a>
                </p>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--Row-->
</div><!--Container-->
```